# OpenERP 6.1 module with upload file field

Tags: python, open-source, odoo

I want to create OpenERP 6.1 module with a upload binary file field as one of the fields in view.

The file will be stored in database as binary data, but before storage in database I need to parse that file, and save data as part of the other created module.

So, I don't know how to specifiy filed for upload files in a view xml file, and also how to run the uploading process. Can somebody help me about this? Some code snippets or advice how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the way [the attachments module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/4178/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py#L142) works, particularly the binary data column. You should also look at [the screen definition](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir.xml#L748).